# Can we use the breadcrumbs just like pagination where a user can go back and forth between the pages?

Tags: navigation, pagination, documentation, breadcrumbs

I want the user to be able to go back and forth on any of these pages. And this is all pdf pages, and the important thing is the hierarchy. In the sales order we are informing how much we will charge on specific usage, so if users have any doubt regarding the invoice charge, they can browse the sales order page to confirm the charges. And if they have any doubts regarding the terms and agreements, they can jump to the page 1 service agreement. These are the internal link docs.

While designing the experience, I thought breadcrumbs was the best option, but the issue is can't hide the last page in hierarchy because these are all pdf files with no way to link from the content. Is this the right approach to do this?

The user will come to this page from the invoice table, so the last page of invoice will appear first when the user taps on the invoice from the table view.

[image]

Comment: Is there really a top-down hierarchy between the pages? It looks more like they belong on the same level. Are tabs more suitable here?

Comment: @jazZRo with the tab view user may not understand hierarchy of the document.

Comment: Ok, and is this hierarchy maybe more like progress steps? The breadcrumbs are used this way as it seems, but are designed as breadcrumbs which is very unusual. So is it an idea to call and design them like a progress steps (as in an order flow, but with back and forth navigation)?

Comment: @jazZRo Yes the user can go back and forth if they have any doubts. Each document have a connection with another doc.

Comment: You're still confusing hierarchy for progression. These pages follow one after another, not one within another.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

By definition itself, **Pagination** is a sequence of pages that are connected and have similar content.

It is important to note that even when the content on a section of a page is split into distinct pages, we will still define that as pagination.

**Breadcrumbs** are a secondary navigation aid that helps users easily understand the relation between their location on a page (like a product page) and higher-level pages (a category page, for instance).

So we can say Breadcrumbs give you an orientation and show you exactly where you are on a website.

Now, if you observe your single page in hierarchy can have multiple page numbers that can be handled with pagination whereas your breadcrumb show where you are as status and not as sole controlled operated.

Answer (score -1):

I am fixing this issue with a visual trick. I merged the concepts of breadcrumbs and tabs to present the hierarchy with a tap option.

[image]

Comment: If this is the additional info to the question please add it in a question and not in the answer section.